# проверка условия данных input

Tags: html, jsp

Может баян, но не нашёл для jsp. Есть выпадающий список select, есть input type='number' и кнопка type='submit'. Задача для разных выбранных значений выпадающего списка сделать свои ограничения min и max для input. Как проверить выбранное значение из списка и отреагировать на него? 
1.Можно при не верном вводе делать кнопку disabled.
2.Можно для каждого выпадающего значения из списка назначить min/max для input
3.Можно проверять правильность введённых в input чисел для каждого выбранного из списка.
Подскажите название функций или где прочитать, реализацию напишу сам.
Нет возможности писать ограничения в классах java.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
document.getElementById('typeAmount').onchange = function(e){
    if (document.getElementById('typeAmount').value>1){
        document.getElementById('density').setAttribute('max','0.7999');
        document.getElementById('density').setAttribute('min','0.6000');
}
    else {
        document.getElementById('density').setAttribute('max','1.0000');
        document.getElementById('density').setAttribute('min','0.8000');
    }
}
</script>
```

решился добавлением javascript